# Tiempo limite para volver a seleccionar un dato

Tags: java, phpmyadmin, jframe, netbeans-8.2, aplicación-escritorio

Hola a todos estoy desarrollando un proyecto de escritorio en `netbeans`, pero quiero agregar una restricción al momento de seleccionar un dato, es decir:
Tengo un `frame` donde muestro los datos del empleado y también un `botón` que abre otro `frame` donde se puede visualizar los empleados que tengo en  `phpmyadmin`, seleccionarlos y enviar los datos a mi primer `frame`, lo que quiero agregar, es que al momento de seleccionar un empleado, no se pueda volver a seleccionarlo hasta después de un cierto tiempo, por ejemplo media hora o 15 minutos.
Eh estado buscando videos y paginas web para poder resolver mi duda y no eh encontrado nada, quisiera saber como puedo hacerlo.Gracias.
-------------------------------IMAGENES----------------------------------

1. Se selecciona el empleado con el `combobox` o con el `botón` buscar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.Al dar click en el boton buscar aparece el frame para selecionar el empleado y enviarlo al primer frame(aqui es donde quiero poner la restriccion del tiempo)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3.Se muestra el empleado que se seleccionó en el `frame` anterior.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sin añadir tu código no podemos ayudarte mucho... si lo que quieres son ideas, ¿por qué no añades una fecha a cada elemento indicando la última vez que se seleccionó?

Comment: Introduce una fecha en el registro del usuario y ten inhabilitada su fila hasta que no se pase el tiempo. Por cierto phpmyadmin no es una base de datos.

Comment: mmm osea agrego una columna en la bd con el nombre fecha???

Comment: lo que quiero hacer es que al momento de seleccionar ese empleado no se pueda seleccionar después de un pequeño tiempo(minutos) 
para ser mas claro esa aplicacion es de un callcenter delivery de una pizzeria, y ese empleado vendria ser el repartidor, no se va a demorar un dia para llevar la pizza, por eso quiero que sea en minutos, no es necesario que se muestre sino que este bloquedo por asi decirlo, como menciona usted @JDev